# Python Interactive Shell - SyntaxError with print

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am new to Python.

I installed Python on my Windows 2003 Virtual Machine; Launched the Python Shell; Typed the following code -

```
print "Hello World"
```

And it spit right back at me the following

> SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Here are some other following statements

```
>>> x = 10

>>> print x
```

> SyntaxError: invalid syntax

The following worked fine though.

```
>>> x
```

> 10

Why wouldn't Python let me write a simple Hello World program?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should say `print(x)` instead.

Comment: Yes this changed with python 3.