# SyntaxError near "print"?

Tags: python, syntax, python-idle

can anybody please tell me why this is giving me syntax error in idle?

```
def printTwice(bruce):
    print bruce, bruce
```

SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: Ah, just add a return there after the colon, don't know why it did that, the syntax error is the first bruce in the statements section

Comment: Check your version of Python. That is invalid in Python 3.x, because `print` is just a function.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7901436/python-print-syntaxerror

Comment: Since the other question has been closed as a duplicate of this, the reference to [PEP 3105](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3105/) which explains what happened had better be brought forward.  This johnny-come-lately question should have been closed as a duplicate of [Python `print` SyntaxError](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7901436/python-print-syntaxerror) rather than that question being closed as a duplicate of this.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python Interactive Shell - SyntaxError with print](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4531083/python-interactive-shell-syntaxerror-with-print)

Answer (score 5):

Check the version of Python being used; the variable [`sys.version`](http://docs.python.org/library/sys.html#sys.version) contains useful information.

That is invalid in Python 3.x, because `print` is *just a normal function* and thus requires parenthesis:

```
# valid Python 3.x syntax ..
def x(bruce): print(bruce, bruce)
x("chin")

# .. but perhaps "cleaner"
def x(bruce):
    print(bruce, bruce)
```

(The behavior in Python 2.x is different, [where `print` was a special statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6182964/why-is-parenthesis-in-print-voluntary-in-python-2-7/6183002#6183002).)

Comment: top show pst, top show, cheers pal.

Answer (score 3):

You seem to be trying to print incorrectly.

You can use a Tuple:

```
def p(bruce):
    print (bruce, bruce) # print((bruce, bruce)) should give a tuple in python 3.x
```

Or you can use formatting in a string in Python ~2.7:

```
def p(bruce):
    print "{0}{1}".format(bruce, bruce)
```

Or use a function in Python 3:

```
def p(bruce):
    print("{0}{1}".format(bruce, bruce))
```