# Syntax error on print statement in python

Tags: python

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [SyntaxError near “print”?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12593502/syntaxerror-near-print)

I've a very weird syntax error right now in python..
Here is the part of code:

```
tradeID = contract.get('tradeId')
itemID = contract.get('itemData').get('id')
if client.buyItem(tradeID, 200):
    print 'Bought Contract for 200 coins'
    if client.moveCard(str(itemID), 'trade'):
        client.postTrade(str(itemID), str(250), str(0), str(3600))
        print 'Contract posted For 250 Coins'
```

It says syntax error for the line `print 'Bought Contract for 200 coins'`

Comment: Please edit this post and correct the indentation. Since Python is whitespace sensative, we can't help you effectively. Also, what version of Python is this?

Comment: is this python 2 or 3? print has changed to a function in python 3.

Comment: @DougT. If it was Python 3, it would raise a SybtaxError at the first print not the second one. **Edit**: oh.... it does...

Comment: What is the point of `str(250)`? Use `'250'` instead directly.

Comment: It is possible that you corrected the syntax error when you posted the code here. Check the line *before* the print statement to check if you have enough closing parenthesis (`)`) to match all the opening parenthesis you have (`(`).

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Python3, you need to treat print like a function:

```
print('Contract posted For 250 Coins')
```

You can use the automated [2to3](http://docs.python.org/2/library/2to3.html) conversion script to generate a diff that will correct most problems like this one.