# SyntaxError: invalid syntax in print 'string1 is: ', string1

Tags: python, compiler-errors

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [SyntaxError near “print”?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12593502/syntaxerror-near-print)

I am a first time user of python. I just got Python 3.3 installed on my computer, got the PATH updated and attempted to run my first python program that I just copied and pasted from a tutorial into a new file. I get an error that reads:

```
File "C:\Users\bmahnke\Desktop\python.py", line 23
      print 'string1 is: ', string1

SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I am not sure what the problem is because I got it from a tutorial site and I'm not certain, but almost, that they wouldn't put a file on there that doesn't compile. So I was wondering what I am doing wrong

Here is the python code that I am using:

```
#! C:\Python33\python.exe

string1 = 'In this class,'
string2 = 'I am learning to program in'
string3 = 'PYTHON.'

print 'string1 is: ', string1
print 'string2 is: ', string2
print 'string3 is: ', string3
print 'Put them altogether and you get:'
print string1, string2, string3
print string1 + string2 + string3
```

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Don't you need to have () around the print statement in python 3?

Comment: And of [Python Interactive Shell - SyntaxError with print](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4531083) (better dupe target).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[In Python 3.3, `print()` is a function](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print) (in Python 2.x, it was a statement). So the correct syntax is now:

```
print('string1 is: ', string1)
```

There is a tool called `2to3.py` which converts Python 2 to 3.

Comment: +1 for mentioning `2to3`

Comment: @BrettMahnke: I advise you to use a different tutorial that focuses on Python 3.  Or perhaps install Python 2.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that in Python 3 `print` is not a statement, but a normal function. Just put `(` and `)` around the arguments to the `print` function and you should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

This code is for Python 2.x. Print statements in Python 3.x are different as per [this section](http://docs.python.org/3.0/whatsnew/3.0.html#print-is-a-function) from the Python documentation:

Answer (score 0):

In python3, `print` is a function:

```
print('string1 is: ', string1)
```

etc